# How to find a value of an attribute of an element

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of code

```
<span class="balance themecolor" data-balance="2800">
```

I'm looking for a way to extract the value of data-balance and set it as variable x, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I know of the existence of **.val()** but I don't know if I can apply it to this code. I'm looking a for a one line long solution.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How is [How do I read an attribute of a HTML tag using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6964909/1529630) not a duplicate? The answer is the same as yours: `attr` or `getAttribute`.

Comment: @Oriol: There are two parts to thsi question: 1. Finding the element. 2. Reading the attribute. So that question's answers do not fully answer *this* question. It probably would in combination with another, though, to be fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery (as you've mentioned `.val()`):

```
var x = $("[data-balance]").attr("data-balance");
```

Or if you aren't:

```
var x = document.querySelector("[data-balance]").getAttribute("data-balance");
```

In both cases, the `[data-balance]` is a CSS selector for the element; adjust as needed. For instance, with that element, and assuming no other elements with either of its classes, you could use `.balance`, `.themecolor`, or even `.balance.themecolor`.

jQuery will find all elements matching the selector (you can change that if it's an issue, usually it isn't), but then only give you the attribute value for the first one.

`querySelector` will stop with the first one. If you want to find them all and get a list, use `querySelectorAll` (and then index into it to get the individual ones).

Comment: How about `jQElem.data('balance')` ? Or with JavaScript, `Element.dataset.balance` ?

Comment: I agree with Rayon its cleaner to use the .data accessor

Comment: @Rayon: I take pains to avoid perpetuating the myth that `.data("foo")` is just shorthand for `.attr("data-foo")`. **It isn't.** It does a lot more work and retains things in memory. In my view, it's best to only do that work and consume that memory when you have need of the features of jQuery's `data` function. Re `dataset`, then you have to get into a whole browser support thing, as **sadly**, there are **still** people targeting IE8 (heaven help them)...

Comment: Hmm interesting. I just always assumed it was a shorthand :)

Comment: @havardhu: Nope. :-) It reads **all** of the `data-*` attributes, parses them, potentially mangles their names, creates an object, puts them on the object, and remembers that object as long as the element exists. Subsequent changes to `data-*` attributes are **not** reflected in that object (and vice-versa).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Cheers, thats nice to know!